# change the range of the pivot table source data

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I want to update the range of the source data my pivot table is reading from to make it more dynamic, however I been getting tons of error code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim Data_sht As Worksheet
Dim Pivot_sht As Worksheet
Dim StartPoint As Range
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PivotName As String
Dim NewRange As String

'Set Variables Equal to Data Sheet and Pivot Sheet
  Set Data_sht = Workbooks("bdncasemacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Filter")
  Set Pivot_sht = Workbooks("bdncasemacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Pivot")

'Enter in Pivot Table Name
  PivotName = "PivotTable4"

'Dynamically Retrieve Range Address of Data
  Set StartPoint = Data_sht.Range("A1")
  Set DataRange = Data_sht.Range(StartPoint, StartPoint.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))

  NewRange = Data_sht.Name & "!" & _
    DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Change Pivot Table Data Source Range Address
  Pivot_sht.PivotTables("PivotTable4").ChangePivotCache _
    Workbooks("bdncasemacro.xlsm").PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=NewRange)

'Ensure Pivot Table is Refreshed
  Pivot_sht.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable

'Complete Message
  MsgBox PivotName & "'s data source range has been successfully updated!"
End Sub
```

one of the error being this:

[image]

Pointing towards the changing source address portion of the code, is there anything I need to add to my code or change? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume it's because you change to a different table with different headers. And that is probably what the error is. You have a header in the pivot table that does not exist in the new table. You could remove all items from the pivot table before doing this. But what is the reason to do this? Why not just have two pivots?

Comment: hi im new to this, im trying to just use one pivot table and update the range it is reading from. im not sure if i have added 2 different headers. which part of the code should i remove with the header to solver the error.

Comment: You need to add code to remove all items from the pivot table first. Not sure what the code is to do that. Record it and modify that slightly.

Comment: The thing that is to be checked first, is your new data source - make sure that this line `Set DataRange = Data_sht.Range(StartPoint, StartPoint.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))` returns a range as described in the error - all columns have to have headers. Headers will become PivotTable fields, if one is missing - pivot table will throw this kind of exception. Try debug this code and find out which line of code generates this error and update your question with this info.

Comment: why not put the input data into a table object? The source for the pivot is then no more the (static) range but the name object. It's best practice, see also [here](https://www.excelcampus.com/pivot-tables/table-source-pivot-table/)